# anaconda to run a script on the fly when activating

Tags: teamcity, pytest, anaconda3

I am using windows cmd scripted jobs in the teamcity configurations. Job basically running the test via direct python invocation

```
set PYTHONPATH=c:\work;%PYTHONPATH;
cd c:\work\test
pytest -v
```

Now we've decided to run testing in anaconda environment, 
and looking for something like

```
conda activate test_env -execute "wrapper.bat"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Any luck on this one @libxelar?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i have done to use conda environment in Teamcity

1. Use powershell build step
2. Create conda environment and set paths

```
conda create -y --name %conda_env_name% python=%python_version%

activate %conda_env_name%

# Created Conda paths to be added to path  
$conda_path = "C:\Program Files\Conda43\envs\" + "%conda_env_name%"
$conda_script = "$conda_path" + "\Scripts"
$conda_lib = "$conda_path" + "\Library\bin"

# Add the newly conda to your path for the session only
$env:Path = "$conda_path;$conda_script;$conda_lib;$env:Path"

#test that it is now using python from the new conda env together with pip
python -V
pip -V
```

3. That's it, run and test it

Comment: `activate` already adds the environment to the path, no need to do that manually (i.e. looks like this does the same thing twice)